# Using MySql variables in UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to have user defined variables, in an UPDATE query like this one.

```
SET content = INSERT(content, @middle_n_pos, 0, ' the appended value '),
@count_n := ROUND( ROUND(   
            ROUND (   
                LENGTH(content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(content, '\n', '')) 
            ) / 2
        ) / 2), 
@middle_n_pos := LOCATE("\n", content, @count_n) 
WHERE content_type = 'type';
```

To put it simple what i am trying to do is count all the \n occurrences in content, and from there get the position of the \n that is in the middle.
After that, insert inside the content a string in the exact position if the \n that is in the middle.